# Nested IF statement to ignore blanks (2)

Tags: excel

i tried below formulae and it is working fine if all four cells are blanks, but if there is a value in A1 and blank in B2, it is showing Conflict and that's not right, i want to see blank.

=IF(A1="","",IF(A1=B2,"Conflict",IF(B1=A2,"Conflict","")))

Please help peeps.
Raj.

Comment: If you sit and list all conditions and sequence them it will become clearer and easier to build the formula. For now, the condition is returning "Conflict" due to `B1` and `A2` being equal from this part `IF(B1=A2,"Conflict","")`.

Comment: *if there is a value in A1 and blank in B2, it is showing Conflict and that's not right, i want to see blank* Sounds like you need to use an OR. So if A1 OR B1 is blank, return blank. Check [Or Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) and see the examples combined with IF.

Comment: HI, below are my logical conditions

IF A1=B2, return CONFLICT IF B1=A2, return CONFLICT IF A1, A2,B1, B2 are empty return nothing

Out of four cells if one of them having value and other 3 are blanks it should return nothing. 

I hope this explains clearly, currently below is the formulae that i am using.

=IF(A1="","",IF(A1=B2,"Conflict",IF(B1=A2,"Conflict","")))

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a value in A1 and blank in B2, it is showing Conflict and that's not right

Actually.. the Excel is right.. it executes as per instructed. Check :

```
A1="" > False
A1=B2 > False
B1=A2 > True
```

That's why yo get that output, not a blank. Meanwhile, to get what you need.. only proceed with the "check" if both of the compared cell are blank.

Here's the implementation :

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),A1=B2),"Conflict",IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)),NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),B1=A2),"Conflict",""))
```

Please share if it works/not. ( :